# Nginx experiencing 502 gateway errors when accessing my site

Tags: php, nginx

I'm experiencing 502 gateway errors when accessing my site from time to time.

Ubuntu 20.04,
Nginx,
PHP-FPM 7.4,
Virtualmin,
Cloudflare

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P4nu2i9D)

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d
[pastepin](https://pastebin.com/4wMahQep)

nginx error log

```
2021/01/02 17:14:00 [error] 56540#56540: *248074 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.114.110.89, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
2021/01/02 17:14:26 [error] 56540#56540: *248088 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.165.247, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/index.php"
2021/01/02 17:15:14 [error] 56540#56540: *248098 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.134.121, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com"
2021/01/02 17:15:43 [error] 56540#56540: *248109 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.114.110.89, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
```

php -i output

https://pastebin.com/He4vUXwK

Answer (score 1):

Your Nginx tries to reach out php at 127.0.0.1:8000, and your php configuration files mention `localhost:8000` and `run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock`.

You should run `php -i` to determine on which adress your php-fpm server is accepting FastCGI requests (sockets, localhost or 127.0.0.1) and adjust your configuration consequently (either configure your php listen param, or your nginx fastcgi address).

Note: it could be possible that your server isn't resolving `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` properly.

Comment: Thank you. this is the output i get when i do php -i  https://pastebin.com/He4vUXwK